# Computed value not updating in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuex, vue-composition-api

I am new to Vue and I am working on a project in which I need to display different components based on a boolean value that shows whether a user is logged in or not.

```
  <template>
    <div class="container-fluid" v-if="isUserLoggedIn">
      <main-navigation/>
      <router-view />
      <MainFooter />
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <router-view />
    </div>
  </template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import MainNavigation from "./MainNavigation.vue";
import MainFooter from "../../common/MainFooter.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    MainNavigation,
    MainFooter,
  },
});
</script>

<script setup>
import { useAuthMethod } from "../../../auth/Auth";
import { computed } from "vue";

const auth = await useAuthMethod();
const isUserLoggedIn = computed(() => auth.isUserLoggedIn());
</script>
```

In the above code the auth.isUserLoggedIn() returns a boolean value indicating if a user is logged in or not. My issue is that the "isUserLoggedIn" const defined by me is not updating automatically or say is not automatically calculating the boolean value and updating the components rendered accordingly.
I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it, so please tell me the correct approach to follow.

I tried removing the "isUserLoggedIn" from computed also but it is of no use, the component does not update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `auth.isUserLoggedIn()` is not reactive, You can make it reactive by assigning its value to a reactive variable and then use that in your computed property. Can you give a try to this **:**

```
const loggedIn = ref(null)

const auth = useAuthMethod();

loggedIn.value = auth.isUserLoggedIn();

const isUserLoggedIn = computed(() => loggedIn.value)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but I tried and it did not work, it is still not updating.

Comment: @VrindaGoyal Ideally this is an issue of reactivity and should reactive. without looking into a whole code it will be difficult to find the root cause of the issue you are facing.